# Geolocation working in Jsfiddle but not in any other JS editor?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

When i am using Gelocation code example on Jsfidlle or google demo example on google developers website , i am able to get the latitude and longitude but when I use that code in some other JS editors i am getting error geolocation service failed

HERE GOES MY CODE

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
var latitude = '';
var longitude = '';
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    alert(latitude);
     });
     } else {
    alert("Geolocation API is not supported");
    };
```

Comment: I am able to run it in plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/JhHVoheFebnSahFX0vDV?p=preview

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @user2181397 What might be the reason that it doesn't works on my localhost server.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan - Why it needs a API key. its an html5 code.

Comment: Sorry I totally misread the question

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Chrome50?
They removed GeoLocation support for non https Sites. but (http://localhost:xx) is still whitelisted for developing

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only